# Wifi Failure after power outage

Tags: wireless, 20.04

My Wifi connection doesn't connect (either automatically or manually) after a power failure, while it gets connected to other systems (mobile/another laptop) easily. The only way it connects is when I restart my laptop.
I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop.  Please help me with this.
Here is the output from lshw -class network

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: enp8s0
       version: 07
       serial: f8:a9:63:91:a2:36
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.11.0-37-generic firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:18 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b2600000-b2600fff memory:b2400000-b2403fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 01
       serial: 00:71:cc:84:39:e9
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8188ee driverversion=5.11.0-37-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:51 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b2500000-b2503fff
```

Comment: As I understand the Wifi-Router has a power-failure and then you can't connect to it. Right?

Comment: Whenever the electricity goes off, so does the wifi router. Once the electricity is back (and so wifi router), my ubuntu doesn't connect while my mobile does.

Comment: What happens when you open the network settings an try to connect to the Wifi-Router [manually](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-connect.html.en)?

Comment: At first, it shows connecting. But after a few seconds, say 10-20, it shows "Unable to connect".

Comment: It shows "modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found".

Comment: Can please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1370646/edit) and add the output of `lshw -class network` to it.

Comment: So this needs to be `sudo modprobe -r rtl8188ee && sleep 5s && sudo modprobe -a rtl8188ee`. Does that work?

Comment: It restarted the network.

Comment: After doing that: Can you now connect to the wifi-router?

Comment: Yes, I can. But don't know whether it will connect to the network after the electricity goes off and then comes back.

Comment: I'd pull the power-plug of the wifi-router to test it. How about that?

Comment: :) I am using university Wifi with wifi-routers installed every few meters. The same network connects to other laptops/mobiles, but they are not affected by the power cut or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably the kernel-driver for your wifi card gets stuck, thus it needs to be restartet like [this answer suggests](https://askubuntu.com/a/1308676/75166).

Your wifi-driver has the name `rtl8188ee` so the command will be:

`sudo modprobe -r rtl8188ee && sleep 5s && sudo modprobe -a rtl8188ee`

Please comment this answer if this didn't improve the situation after a power-outage.

Comment: Hi @MadMike. So the above solution you provided worked like a miracle all the time until a few days ago,  I am not able to join any wifi network except for the mobile hotspot.     It keeps showing Activation or Network connection failed

Comment: My answer is just a workaround for an underlying problem. It could either be a software (Linux driver)-problem or a hardware problem. If you google `unreliable linux wifi RTL8188EE` you find problem reports dating back to 2013. If the problem could be solved by a better Linux-driver it would be have been done by that way until now. So I conclude the hardware is the issue here. Switch the hardware. Switching the internal card won't be easy. Adding a usb wifi adapter will be easier (but won't look as good and will be fidgety). Search for `linux usb wifi adapter`.